# NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I am trying to run a simple spring hibernate program. Compilation is successful. when I try to run the main method I am getting the following exception in console

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.setEnvironment(Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;)V
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:86)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:612)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:513)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.newt.rollback.main.RollBackSample.main(RollBackSample.java:13)
```

Please help me to overcome this...

Answer (score 0):

This usually occurs when you haven't added all required dependencies. Make sure that you require all of them in your `build.xml` or `pom.xml`

If you are using maven, then try to add these dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Previously I didn't add spring-web and spring-webmvc dependencies. Now I added and tried. But still I am facing the same exception. Please provide your valuable comments..